# Run jQuery plugin on TinyMCE content

Tags: jquery-plugins, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a jQuery plugin (`jQuery.fn.myJQueryPlugin`) that loads on a page that also loads a TinyMCE editor.

Is there a way I can get the plugin to work on the content of the TinyMCE editor (via a TinyMCE plugin)?

I've tried something along the lines of

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'myTinyMCEPlugin', function( editor ) {
    editor.on('PostProcess', function(event){
        editor.getWin().parent.jQuery(".trigger-class").myJQueryPlugin();
    });
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it turns out, it can be done:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'myTinyMCEPlugin', function( editor ) {
    editor.on('PostProcess', function(event){
        // get jQuery from parent window
        $ = editor.getWin().parent.jQuery;
        $(".trigger-class", editor.getDoc()).myJQueryPlugin();
    });
});
```